# Flatten nested json with array into single line dataframe in Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to flatten the below json into a single lined dataframe. I've seen plenty of articles showing how to flatten a complex/nested json object with arrays into multiple lines. However, I don't want to flatten the json into multiple lines. I just wanted a single lined dataframe as shown in the output. The array indices are converted into columns names. How can I accomplish this in Apache Spark Scala?

JSON

```
{
 "name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "bike":{
    "name":"Bajaj", "models":["Dominor", "Pulsar"]
    },
 "cars": [
   { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
   { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
   { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
 ]
}
```

OUPUT

```
name | age | bike_name | bike_models_0 | bike_models_1 | cars_0_name | cars_0_modesl_0 | ... | cars_1_name | cars_1_models_0 | ...
John   30    Bajaj       Dominor         Pulsar          Ford          Fiesta                  BMW           320
```

Comment: Just curious what are you planning to do based on the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colname[index]` to access values from an array and `parentcol.childcol` to access nested column.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

val json =
      """
        |{
        | "name":"John",
        | "age":30,
        | "bike":{
        |    "name":"Bajaj", "models":["Dominor", "Pulsar"]
        |    },
        | "cars": [
        |   { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        |   { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        |   { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
        | ]
        |}
        |
        |""".stripMargin

val df = spark.read.option("multiline", true).json(Seq(json).toDS())

df.selectExpr("name", "age",
      "bike.name bike_name", "bike.models[0] bike_models_0", "bike.models[1] bike_models_1",
      "cars[0].name cars_0_name", "cars[0].models[0] cars_0_models_0", "cars[0].models[1] cars_0_models_1", "cars[0].models[2] cars_0_models_2",
      "cars[1].name cars_1_name", "cars[1].models[0] cars_1_models_0", "cars[1].models[1] cars_1_models_1", "cars[1].models[2] cars_1_models_2",
      "cars[2].name cars_2_name", "cars[2].models[0] cars_2_models_0", "cars[2].models[1] cars_2_models_1"
    ).show(false)
/*
+----+---+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|name|age|bike_name|bike_models_0|bike_models_1|cars_0_name|cars_0_models_0|cars_0_models_1|cars_0_models_2|cars_1_name|cars_1_models_0|cars_1_models_1|cars_1_models_2|cars_2_name|cars_2_models_0|cars_2_models_1|
+----+---+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|John|30 |Bajaj    |Dominor      |Pulsar       |Ford       |Fiesta         |Focus          |Mustang        |BMW        |320            |X3             |X5             |Fiat       |500            |Panda          |
+----+---+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+*/
```

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically get the field names rather than hardcoding them in?